# How to add Facebook/Twitter/LinkedIn login to Google App Engine project?

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook, oauth, openid, twitter-oauth

I've searched for solutions, but everything I can find seems mostly outdated.

We're using the Python API for GAE and creating login urls in the following manner:

```
users.create_login_url(continue_url, "Yahoo", "http://yahoo.com/"),
```

Which works fine for sites such as Google, Yahoo, Aol, Blogger, Flickr, etc... but we're aware that Facebook and Twitter don't work in this manner.

Can anyone show any examples of how to authenticate users on App Engine using Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn?

Thanks!

Comment: For facebook, there is a python sdk https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, one has to register their application on Facebook and get an Application ID.  Details:
[Register here](http://developers.facebook.com/setup/)  [Facebook authentication overview](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login)

Then, I used the facebook python SDK, along with the facebook javascript api (which is the canonical way to do authentication with facebook).  [Here's a working example of authenticaion I used.](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/appengine/example.py)

[Direct link to the Facebook python SDK](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk)

[Direct link to the Facebook Javascript SDK](https://github.com/facebook/connect-js)

Comment: Note that Facebook has since then dropped support for both the Python and JavaScript SDKs

Answer (score 1):

If the service you want to sign in with doesn't support OpenID, you need to do it the same way you would on any other service: Set up your own sessions library, handle logins in a site-specific manner, and keep track of signed in user sessions using the session library.